# How to physically handle hundreds and hundreds of papers

Tags: tools, grading

I have a bit of a meta-question about academics.

I am a graduate student and teaching assistant.  I often find myself flipping, organizing, and searching through stacks of hundreds and hundreds of sheets of paper, whether I'm grading, reading, or doing research.

I seem to have an issue where my hands get dry quickly, and I find myself licking the tips of my fingers to get better friction.  Sometimes I have to do this quite often, and I am wondering if there is a better way.  I tried using hand moisturizer, but that wears off.

Are there special gloves, lotions, or anything that can help with flipping through huge stacks of paper?

Comment: unless you have acquired a particular liking for the taste of paper (or your finger), I suggest you use a digital library manager (preferably one that allows you to categorize and keep track of your lecture notes as well)

Comment: @posdef this would not be useful for when you are grading papers, since they are seldom submitted electronically.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev true, I had not thought of that... However, one *could* scan those papers to a single PDF (easily doable on most office-grade multi-function printers), then annotate/review/grade the papers, and print out the PDF. If there are really so many papers so that handling them is a significant problem, digitalizing them is a viable option

Comment: We are looking into converting our assignments into more electronic-friendly versions, but we aren't there yet, and there are many, many papers to grade in the meantime.

Comment: @posdef: Just *getting* that many papers into a scanner will require a lot of handling.  All the bulk scanners I've used have a nontrivial jam rate.  And in the case of things like exam papers that will only be handled one, I doubt that digitizing will be worth the time.

Comment: @posdef: You're suggesting exactly the opposite of the grading workflow I find most effective: Print out the electronically submitted files, mark them up by hand, and then scan them back in (which is easier because they're all on the same paper stock).

Comment: See discussion about this question on meta: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/443/102

Comment: You ask for a tool that would make flipping through papers easier, but you could greatly reduce the need for this tool by eliminating shuffled stacks. Use folders and filing cabinets or boxes (sometimes called "banker's boxes") and group related papers together, and you won't have to flip through as much. Also, papers in vertical folders tend to spread out so that they are easier to flip through and retrieve.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some 20 years ago before all the electronics changed our ways of dealing with stuff, post and bank employees who had to deal with piles of paper (or banknotes) throughout day used a device which was essentially a piece of a wet sponge in a small bowl. They had this on the desk and whenever were about to touch paper, they would simply brush their fingers through it. Something like that could help you... To construct it, I would use a plastic travel-soap container and a small sponge for dishwashing.

**Later edit:** Indeed, [this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wet%20fingers%20bank%20post%20sponge&um=1&tbm=isch) is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to walkmanyi's wetting solution would be to employ [rubber finger tips](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber%20finger%20tips&aq=1&oq=rubber%20fi&aqs=chrome.3.0j57j5j0.14822&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

**On the plus side:**
They protect from drying out of the natural oil from your finger tips, and protect against paper cuts.
**On the negative side:**
Well you are wearing little caps on the tips of your fingers and you lose some tactile feedback. I imagine it would take some getting used to.